# Guestbook Title

Tags: 7, string-overrides

I have installed the guestbook module but want to change the tab as displayed in the user profile and the text in the link so that they read 'User Feedback' rather than 'User Guestbook'
and 'add feedback' rather than 'add guestbook entry'

Looked everywhere but can't find where to change the field label

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[string overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) works in almost every case ;),
but there might be a nicer method, like hooking some methods of the gb module.

Comment: Hi...thanks for the advice. 
I loaded the string overrides module and managed to change the link no probs...but can't figure out how to change the tab. 

Currently it says robbiemc's guestbook but obviously can't move to override robbiemc....any ideas...?

Cheers

R

Comment: Hi
Got it...used @username's guestbook and changed to username's feedback.
Thanks for the help
R